# Customize selected value with el-select

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus

I need to customize the selected value in the el-select component, so far I've only found documentation and examples about customizing the option items but not the value once is selected. Is this possible with `element-plus`? If so, please add an example or point me in the right direction.

These are the options customized with custom HTML using a slot

[image: Options customized]

Here is how it looks once is been selected, I need to display just as the option is, using custom html

[image: Once is selected, I want to display the selected value just as the option is]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a prototype for this:

[image]

[Source Code](https://github.com/wenfangdu/el-plus-repro/tree/so-68697971)

```html
<template>
  <el-select
    v-model="selected"
    value-key="price"
    :placeholder="selected ? '' : 'Please Select'"
    clearable
  >
    <el-option v-for="item in options" :value="item">
      <div class="option-grid">
        <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
        <div class="desc">{{ item.desc }}</div>
        <div class="price">{{ item.price }}</div>
      </div>
    </el-option>

    <template v-if="selected" #prefix>
      <div class="option-grid prefix">
        <div class="title">{{ selected.title }}</div>
        <div class="desc">{{ selected.desc }}</div>
        <div class="price">{{ selected.price }}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </el-select>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const options = Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, i) => {
    const n = i + 1

    return {
      title: `Title ${n}`,
      desc: `Description ${n}`,
      price: `Price ${n}`,
    }
  })

  const selected = ref(null)
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .el-select-dropdown__item {
    height: max-content;
  }

  .option-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      'title price'
      'desc  price';
    line-height: 1.2;
    .title,
    .desc {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .title,
    .price {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .title {
      grid-area: title;
    }
    .desc {
      grid-area: desc;
    }
    .price {
      grid-area: price;
      justify-self: end;
      align-self: center;
    }
    &.prefix {
      width: 196px;
      color: var(--el-text-color-regular);
      .title,
      .desc {
        justify-self: start;
        padding-left: 20px;
      }
    }
    &:not(.prefix) {
      .title {
        padding-top: 4px;
      }
      .desc {
        padding-bottom: 4px;
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I need to customize / add html to the selected option. Your solution is to do something once the selected value changes

Comment: @GeneralElectric Can you give an example of in which way do you want to change the selected option?

Comment: Please check my edit, I've included pictures

Comment: @GeneralElectric Unfortunately, I don't think that's achievable, since the selected option doesn't have a dedicated slot, your best bet is to include the details in the option's label.

Comment: that's a bummer, I'd leave this on for sometime in case anyone else have a workaround

Comment: @GeneralElectric I reread the documentation and found the `prefix` slot might be suitable for this, I've updated my answer, please see above.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question for elements-ui in Vue2.
Here is an updated fiddle for Vue3 and ElementsPlus: https://jsfiddle.net/fmay24ru/8/

Unfortunately there is still no other possibility than using the `#prefix` if you want to style the result.
But if you just want to display other or more values, than `:label` is the best way to go.